# Converting shoucast statistics

Tags: php, shoutcast

I have this script to check the song title and streamname (DJ) listeners but it doesn't always work like it should

it should be if status 1 show what the stats grab else show offline. but it doesn't want to work, I got this code off a friend he doesn't want to recode it but I have no idea how to make it work with shoutcast 2.0

heres the code

```
<?php

  class radioStuff {

/**
    Shoutcast specific class to grab server stats
*/

private $url = "http://sc.*REMOVED*.co.uk";
private $port = 80;

private $json_object;

public function __construct() {

    $ch = curl_init();
    // Disable SSL verification
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    // Will return the response, if false it print the response
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    // Set the url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$this->url . ':' . $this->port . '/stats?json=1');
    // Execute
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    // Closing
    curl_close($ch);

    $this->json_object = json_decode($result);
}

public function getHabboUrl() {
    $imageString =  'http://www.habbo.com/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?user=' .     $this->json_object->servergenre . '&direction=4&head_direction=3&action=wlk&gesture=sml';

    return $imageString;
}

public function getCurrentListeners() {

    return $this->json_object->currentlisteners;
}
 public function getSTATUS() {

    return $this->json_object->streamstatus;
}
    public function getCurrentDJ() {

    return $this->json_object->servertitle;
}
   public function getCurrentSong() {

    return $this->json_object->songtitle;
   }
 }

$radio = new radioStuff();


if($radio->getSTATUS == 1) {

 $response = array(
 'dj' => 'Radio statistics are offline!',
 'song' => 'We are offline!', 'listeners' => ''
 );
 header('Content-Type: application/json');
 echo json_encode($response);


  } else {

 $response = array(
 'dj' => $radio->getCurrentDJ(),
 'song' => $radio->getCurrentSong(),
 'listeners' => $radio->getCurrentListeners()
  );
   header('Content-Type: application/json');
   echo json_encode($response);

   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in you code:

`if($radio->getSTATUS == 1) {`

should be

`if($radio->getSTATUS() == 1) {`

`getSTATUS` is a function, so you should call it with `()`

Also, if stream status is `1` - the stream is alive and if stream status is 0 - then your station is offline, so replace 1 with 0 in your comparison.

Comment: I need a little more help with this script

Comment: This is supposed to work for shoutcast 1.0 can you get it to work for shoutcast 2.0

`public function radioInfo( $url ) {
   
   $opts = array(
   
    'http' => array(
    
     'method' => 'GET',
     'header' => 'User-Agent: SHOUTcast Song Status (Mozilla Compatible)\r\n'
    
    )
   
   );

   $context = stream_context_create( $opts );

   $data    = @file_get_contents( $url, false, $context );

   if( preg_match( "/Stream is currently up and private (not listed)/", $data ) ) {
   
    $return['online'] = true;
`

Comment: I have tested your script on Shoutcast 2 server and it works.

Comment: It' does grab correclt. that's not the whole script